# can callback functions access parent function variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a load(callback) function which takes a callback function as parameter. Can this callback function access variables present in its parent function i.e. load()

```
(function load(callback) 
{                
    return $.get("../somepage.aspx", {data:data},  function (response, status, xhr){   
        var x = 10; 
        if(typeof callback === 'function') { callback(); }
    }
})(done);

var done = function(){
  //do something with x here
  alert(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access `x` like you want because it is outside the [*scope*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) of the `done` function.

You need to pass `x` to the callback:

```
(function load(callback) 
{                
    return $.get("../somepage.aspx", {data:data},  function (response, status, xhr){   
        var x = 10; 
        if(typeof callback === 'function') { callback(x); }
    }
})(done);

var done = function(x){
  //do something with x here
  alert(x);
}
```

I *suspect* this is what you want but to but I am taking a stab in the dark here seeing as how the code in the question has serious syntax problems (i.e. `done` is not a `child` of parent.)

Comment: @fuyushimoya Thanks. Updated.

Comment: This does not answer the question. He is asking about accessing parent variables

Comment: @leo.fcx Admittedly I am taking a stab in the dark here seeing as how the code in the question has serious syntax problems (i.e. `done` is not a child of `parent`.)

Comment: @Petrichor, agree. Actually, IMO that explanation should go in the answer :)

Comment: @Petriocher thnks a lot that helps!!

Comment: @user3399326 Awesome - I'm glad. Does that answer your question, then?

Comment: @Petrichor yes it does. thnks!!

Comment: @leo.fcx Turns out it did answer the question, Leo :P

Comment: @user3399326 Awesome. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it can't because the callback's scope is totally outside the calling scope. Pass x as a parameter in the callback.